# Adding cell value to another cell in the same datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is that possible to add the value of this cell? because im planning to make 1 total of a day sale of may system

[image]

Comment: Can you give more detail how you using that cell and what you want?

Comment: What are you asking about??? Code example?

Comment: @Uday because im making this system like point of sale system, then i want the sales of every transaction that i made are save and to be total

Comment: @JackM Yes, Can I? so i can have an Idea pls.

Comment: @jezreelronsairo do you want make total of any column?

Comment: @Uday No, I'm thinking it would be more organize if i put it on another table with the date of that day and the total sales of that day :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are doing this with dataset, you can do like this

```
DataTable table;
table = dataSet.Tables["TableName"];

// Declare an object variable.
object sumObject;
sumObject = table.Compute("Sum(total)", "");
```

Comment: Thanks For the Code, I will try This :)

Comment: where are you getting this table data?

Comment: i Would like to get the all value of every transaction that day in the grid and make a total of that day from another grid

Comment: you mean to say that in image above you have multiple dates? and what do you mean by another grid?

Comment: It just an Example that the value 2890 + 1450 + 4925 = 9265, the 9265 i want it to put to another grid as the whole total of the transaction

Comment: so meaning every transaction of that day will be add and save to another grid

Comment: so whats the problem you have the total. Simply get this value and update it into your second datatable and bind your second grid to that table. This is what i got from this comment ... @jezreelronsairo

Comment: Upvote if this helps buddy.. time off from office now :P

Comment: Hahahahha Anyway Thanks for your Time Buddy, I cant Up Vote Yet, I Only Got 12 Rep. :)

Comment: well you can mark it as answer if this helped you @jezreelronsairo